# I'm trying to have a nested router outlet in Angular 5 but its not working

Tags: angular

In my app.module.ts, I have routes for a navbar

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'angular5',component:Angular5MainComponent},
  {path:'',redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'**', component:HomeComponent}
]),
```

I have router-outlet tag for this. 
On opening one of these pages , I have an option for a side navbar with many options. So I created a Module for that too called angular5.module.ts

```
    RouterModule.forChild([
     {path:'HistoryOfAngular', component: HistoryOfAngular}
    ])
```

I have a router-outlet tag for this too. But its not working

Answer (score 0):

create your array like this and use only

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

{
    path: '', component: RootComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
    ]
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },];
```

Comment: check now 
there was my mistack i have put forChild instead of forRoot

Comment: Still nothing! I have two router-outlet tags. Is that okay